# sort documents by effective date

Tags: sorting, groovy

Each document ( inputStream IS) has field called effective date. I need all these individual documents to be combined into one document sorted by effective date.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;

for( int i = 0; i < dataContext.getDataCount(); i++ ) {
  InputStream is = dataContext.getStream(i);
  Properties props = dataContext.getProperties(i);
  dataContext.storeStream(is, props);
}
```

Thanks
Nag

Answer (score 0):

Add your documents to an `ArrayList`, then use `List.sort(Comparator)` with a comparator that compares the dates. After that iterate over the `List` with a for-each loop and add the documents to your output.

Comment: Oh, wait, your code looks very Java-like. Is this question about Java or really about Groovy? You can use my suggestion in Groovy too of course, but your code ist not really groovy-like. :-)

Comment: And what kind of class is `dataContext`? Is this an own class? Following some interface?